# Writing a string to a file only writes ... byte array address?

Tags: java, android, file, arrays

I have a pretty weird problem. I wanted to write something (actually a `String`) to a file. I converted it into a byte array as usual, wrote that into the file and... there is only something written like: `[B@42928da8`. No matter what i write, how big that string is, or else, i don't get something much different. I'm  thinking that that is an address to the array but how did it get there?

The function which is called when the "save" button is pressed.

```
public void saveNote(View view){
    String FILENAME;
    String content;


    FILENAME = editText_name.getText().toString();
    content = editText_note.getText().toString();

    if (FILENAME.equals("LISTOFALLNOTES") || FILENAME.equals("TMP")){
        if(requestdecision(getString(R.string.note_warning)))
        {

        }
        else
            return;
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        showmessage("Fehler beim Erstellen der Datei");
    }
    try {
        fos.write(content.getBytes());
        fos.close();

        showmessage("Erfolgreich gespeichert!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        showmessage("Fehler beim Schreiben");
    }

}
```

`showmessage()` is only a function which shows a simple info dialog.

I thank you for your advice.

EDIT: I just found out that if you reopen the notice/file the output changes. So I posted the reading function(s) here:

```
public void openNote(View view){
    String FileName=editText_name.getText().toString();
    if (FileName.equals("LISTOFALLNOTES") || FileName.equals("TMP") || FileName.equals("MAIN_DATA")){
        if(requestdecision(getString(R.string.note_warning)))
            {}
        else
            return;
    }
    editText_note.setText(readNote(FileName).toString());
}


public String readNote(String name){
    File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), name);
    int length = (int) file.length();
    String contents;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];


    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        showmessage("Datei nicht gefunden");
        e.printStackTrace();
        contents = "";
    }
    try {
        in.read(bytes);
        in.close();
        contents=bytes.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        showmessage("Konnte nicht lesen");
        e.printStackTrace();
        contents = "";
    }
}
```

Weird is also why that changes. Doesn't that somehow mean that the file is saved during the reading process?

Edit2: I just discovered that the file itself(read with a root filebrowser) is written normally so the problem has to be in the reading process.

Comment: What is the return type of `editText_note.getText()` ?

Comment: It actually is called Editable.

Comment: Looks like you are getting the `toString()` of the object not the actual text contents.

Comment: I don't know about android but problem is that you are calling toString() on the byte []. if editText_note.getText() returns a byte [] use that in fos.write() instead of calling toString() on editText_note.getText() and then calling getBytes().

Comment: Hmm... Even the develop guide of android itself does editText.getText().toString() and its definetly not returning a byte array

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue like this before. What fixed it for me was not directly calling the `content.getBytes()` directly into the into the write method, but first making sure it's labeled as a byte array and then writing through the `FileOutputStream`.

```
String n_content = (String)content;
byte[] bContent = n_content.getBytes;
fos.write(bContent);
```

If this ceases to work I believe your `openFileOutput()` isn't returning a proper `FileOutputStream` instance.

Comment: what do you mean with "isn't returning a proper FileOutputStream instance"? Why should openFileOutput return a weird, or even damaged not-working FileOutputStream?

Comment: I wasn't sure wether or not you made that method, sorry. I was curious because generally what you would have done is create a new instance without the use of a method.